# Need help terminating program when secret number is found

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a c program that uses a function that adds 2 integers to a random number. Which I have accomplished below. My problem is, I set a variable to a secret number and when that number is found, I need the program to terminate and it does not.

```
int x,y,secretnumber;

secretnumber = 5;

do
{
    printf("Please enter two integers to be added together to a random number from 0-99 \n"
    "Keep entering numbers until you hit the secret number!\n");
    scanf("%i%i", &x, &y);

    if(sumintsrand(x,y) != secretnumber)
    {
        printf("The summation of integers %i and %i and a random number is %i \n\n",x,y,sumintsrand(x,y));
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You have found the secret number: %i! Goodbye!\n", secretnumber);
    }
}
while(sumintsrand(x,y) != secretnumber);

return 0;
}



int sumintsrand(int x, int y)
{

int sumintsrand = x + y + rand()%5;

 return sumintsrand;
}
```

If anyone has any idea where I'm going wrong I would really appreciate it

Comment: I guess it's because the random in sumintsrand() is getting generated each time it is called, so the answer in the while() end is different to the one in your if().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I compiled your program with my earlier suggested mod, and I didn't get silly large numbers, so pass on that - different question?

It seems a bit strange to keep changing the random number - the same guess might fail once but work the next time. Also there is a confusion about whether the range is 5 or 99.

So I've simplified your work, to make you guess two numbers that sum to the secret number. If that's not your intention, perhaps you can draw on my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

#define MAXVAL 5

int main(){
    int x, y, secretnumber, testval;
    srand ((unsigned)time(NULL));
    secretnumber = rand() % (MAXVAL+1);
    do
    {
        printf("Enter two integers to be added to equal a secret random number from 0-%d\n"
               "Keep entering numbers until you hit the secret number!\n", MAXVAL);
        if (scanf("%d%d", &x, &y) != 2)
            return 0;                       // exit program
        testval = x + y;
        if(testval != secretnumber)
            printf("Sorry - try again!\n\n");
        else
            printf("You have found the secret number: %d + %d = %d! Goodbye!\n", 
                    x, y, secretnumber);
    }
    while(testval != secretnumber);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but now my answers are huge numbers. Like i will type 1 + 2 + random number and it will return a huge number. what's going on?

Comment: @GabriellaCoronell I have reposted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your sumintsrand() function thrice. Each time, the result of the function is going to be different based on what rand() returns.

Your call to sumintsrand()within the while loop may have found the secret number, but that is not retained. You need to store it for checking whether while loop needs to be terminated.

UPDATE:

```
int sum = 0;
do {

   scanf("%i%i", &x, &y);
   sum = sumintsrand(x,y);

} while(sum != secretnumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working, because in that line `while(sumintsrand(x,y) != secretnumber);` you are calling `sumintsrand` a second time - and it gives other result.

Possible solutions:

1. Save the result of first call of `sumintsrand` and check if it(the saved result) is the same as `secretnumber`
2. Use `break`
3. Make `bool` variable which will end the loop - at the beginning it will be `true`, when you will find the number just set it to `false`.